# PHP get user's local time (in SMF)

Tags: php, function, time, local, smf

I know php isn't very handy when it gets to fetching local time because it requires the user to have a cookie with the corresponding offset. I'm looking to get a value for the user's time using SMF (which should already have this information in the databse). I couldn't find out how to do this by using smf's site, so I'm asking here.

If you're wondering why, it's because I have 2 themes a "day" and a "night" theme. I want the night one to be displayed if the time falls between the two corresponding times.

BTW you can see these themes here: http://hetoan2.com/forum and night: http://hetoan2.com/forum?v=night

thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily the best way would just be to use the `Date()` method in JavaScript. This gives you the date and time of the user's machine.

If, however, you only want to use php (for whatever reason), you could use a geolocation tool like [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/index.php) to get the users current location and then use `date_default_timezone_set` to set the timezone of the user to the timezone of your server, and then get the date that way.